# python import cx_Oracle error

Tags: python, django, cx-oracle, inspectdb

I'm trying to install cx_Oracle to use Django inspectdb on an existing Oracle database to create models.py automatically. So far i'ts been very hard. I'm running a VM with Fedora 14 64bit and Python 2.7 and followed a mix of pages found with google to get it installed with sudo -E easy_install cx_Oracle

When I fire up python from terminal and try to import cx_Oracle to test the installation I get this:

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

I've never seen this before and don't know what to do. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Stefano

Comment: Not sure about this, but can you try downloading the cx_Oracle rpm directly, and ensure that you choose the 64-bit version. Remove your current cx_Oracle installation first.

Answer (score 1):

It was SELinux, Fedora security system that was blocking it and I didn't notice! Installation was ok and it's working now. Sorry and thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It has occurred for me long time back

There are two set of libraries for 32 bit and 64 bit just copy these "*.so" files to the appropriate directories.

Please note there are more than 1 file[around 5 i guess] to be copied . just use a find command to locate your present location of libclntsh.so file and copy it to the respective lib directories. you can find the rest of the files since same exception pops up for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the instantclient path in ldconfig; adding it will fix this problem.